# Xamarin.Forms Error when navigate to another page in button_clicked

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, onclick

In my Xamarin.Forms project I have a SplashScreen for Android and an AppDelegate for IOS that check some conditions and then pass some data to App.xaml.cs . Then :

```
public App(string isLogin)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (isLogin == "Nologin")
                App.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
            else
            {
                switch (isLogin)
                {
                    case "Update": 
                            App.Current.MainPage = new MessagePage("Some Message");
                        break;

                    case "Internet":
                        App.Current.MainPage = new MessagePage("Some Message");
                        break;

                    default:
                        App.Current.MainPage = new MainPage(isLogin);
                        break;
                }
            }


        }
```

Now in the MessagePage I have this :

```
private async void RefreshButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string result = await AppStart.DoStartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (result == "Login")
           await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
}
```

that show this error :

System.InvalidOperationException: 'PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.'

and if I use this :

```
if (result == "Login")
    Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
```

Show this error :

Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: 'Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.'

What can I do ?

Comment: Try to use `Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());` to replace `Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());` in your `RefreshButton_Clicked` method.

Comment: Thank you . This code show this error : Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: 'Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.'

Comment: in App.xaml.cs I changed `new LoginPage()` to `new NavigationPage( new LoginPage())` but still this error is here : Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: 'Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.'

Comment: Can you share your `SplashActivity` code? I make a splash actvity and test your code, it worked as normal. Here is running GIF. https://imgur.com/a/G7TJTFL  based on your error message, it seems that you open a thread in the `SplashActivity` or other pages, when you navigate to loginpage, MessagePage are not in the main thread, please refer to this similar thread:https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30804/exception-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-views

Comment: Oh , thank you . this change solved my problem `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
                });`

Comment: If my comment solved your issue, can I move the comment to asnwer? Then you accept it as answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: @MSFT oh yes sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your error message. 
`Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: 'Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

This issue is related to the you update the view not in the UI thread(Main thread), you should wrap you update view code by `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(Action)` to make sure any UI updates are occurring on the correct thread.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
 async () => { 
     await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
 });
```

Comment: Thank you bro . this code solved my problem . Of course I changed my App.xaml.cs to `App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MessagePage("Some Message"));`